# R: How to plot multiple boxplots, each from a single column in a dataset, on the same ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have the following data table of this structure:

```
+-----+-------+-------+-------+
| key | col1  | col2  | col3  |
+-----+-------+-------+-------+
| A   | 1000  | 56    | 1     |
| A   | 2000  | 3     | NaN   |
| B   | 2001  | 23    | 90    |
| A   | 2002  | 87    | 42    |
| A   | 2004  | 12    | 12    |
| B   | 2002  | 1     | NaN   |
| C   | 2002  | 3     | 14    |
+-----+-------+-------+-------+
```

My objective is to plot 1 ggplot of multiple boxplots for each key, where each boxplot in the ggplot is the visualization of every column in the dataset. Is there anyway to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understood

```
 df <- structure(list(key = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("A", 
    "B", "C"), class = "factor"), col1 = c(1000L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 
    2004L, 2002L, 2002L), col2 = c(56L, 3L, 23L, 87L, 12L, 1L, 3L
    ), col3 = c(1, NaN, 90, 42, 12, NaN, 14)), .Names = c("key", 
    "col1", "col2", "col3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -7L))

library(reshape2)
df1 <- melt(df)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(aes(x = variable, y = value), data = df1) + geom_boxplot() + facet_wrap(~key)
```

[image]

or

```
ggplot(aes(x = variable, y = value), data = df1) + geom_boxplot() + facet_wrap(variable~key)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Mateusz1981 thank you for your help. Sorry for the poor description of the problem I have. I actually am looking to have 1 facet be 1 variable for each key.

Comment: Thank you for the examples. Helped a bunch!

Comment: you may also want to change the argument `scales` in `facet_*`